# Compute sum for summer months

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, case-when

Table schema:

```
Reader_id
Date
Minutes_read
Book_id
```

I want to extract the month from a date ‘2021-07-15’ to sum the total time spent reading books in summer months (06-08) for each reader.

So my final table would something like

```
Reader_id | summer_reading_time
```

Answer (score 3):

If your data spans multiple years, you cannot simply extract a time range. Consider [`EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
SELECT Reader_id, sum(Minutes_read) AS summer_reading_time
FROM   tbl
WHERE  EXTRACT(month FROM date) BETWEEN 6 AND 8
GROUP  BY 1;
```